# Calculate or evaluate double trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to calculate:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\varphi}{1+\left(\cos2\theta-\cos\varphi \right)^2} \cos\left(j\varphi\right) d\varphi \right) \cos\left(2^i \theta\right)d\theta$$
where $i,j\in\mathbb N$.

I tried with integration by parts for:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\varphi}{1+\left(\cos2\theta-\cos\varphi \right)^2} \cos\left(j\varphi\right) d\varphi $$
but I came up with nothing. Maybe it is unmanageable. What do you think?

Comment: Is this part of a summation?

Comment: Yes, is it important?

Comment: @Mark Depending on the summation, it could potentially be easier to do the sum first before integrating.

Comment: It seems, that for odd j or odd i or both odd i and j, the integral is zero

Comment: I think one has to use Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind, to get more insight

Comment: @Mark I tried  with the terms, the only progress I achive is to split the integral in two parts, which converge [Dieckman](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html): See Partial Fraction Decompositions

Comment: @stocha, thank you. Could you write your attempt?

Comment: @Mark It is not possible to post the answer because while writing they upvote me!

Comment: i like this question, let me check a paper

Comment: I managed to integrate over $\varphi$